# How to add pug to angular-cli?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, pug

Anyone having luck adding .pug to angular-cli?

I tried to do npm install pug --save, but I don't know where to change the .pug rendering instead of .html.

Link for the angular-cli is [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)

Please share a short tutorial, that would help a lof of people :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Angular 6+ you can simply run **ng add ng-cli-pug-loader** command in the root folder to turn on pug support in your angilar-cli project.

Answer (score 7):

So after reading on angular-cli git, implementing pug is not in the near future.

So here is my workaround: It's not the angular-cli, but its an updated generator that runs angular2 final.

Use angular2-webpack generator from AngularClass - [here](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter)
(Just follow the well documented instructions)

Want pug? no problem, just follow the link [here](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-add-.pug-support)

Want Scss? no problem, just follow the link [here](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-include-SCSS-in-components)

To keep it short, just do the npm installing and add those line in webpack.common file. And use require() in your component with ./filename.pug :) but follow the links and you'll be fine.

Thanks AngurlarClass <3

This was was what I was looking for - angular2, typescript, scss and pug.. Yum Yum!

```js
      loaders: [
        { 
          test: /\.pug$/, 
          loader: 'pug-html-loader' 
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] // sass-loader not scss-loader
        },
```

Comment: If you want sass instead of scss. Just replace test: /\.scss$/ with test: /\.sass$/ and rename your files from .scss to .sass

Comment: Do you have any git-repo with this configuration ?

Comment: @Vivek-Doshi here's one setup with localstorage, pug, sass, angular2, webpack2, a bit of animation https://github.com/theklausster/sweco feel free to rip it off :)

Answer (score 4):

Using [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) you can do this workaround.

- Install [pug-cli](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-cli) using `npm install pug-cli --save-dev`. Now you are able to compile your `.pug` files into `.html`.
- Add a new `script` line into your `package.json`'s scripts: `"puggy": "pug src -P -w"`. This will compile all your `.pug` inside `src` into `.html` and starts watching them. Name of the task, of course, does not matter.
- Edit your `start` task, or create a new one, to first run `puggy` and then `serve`: `"start" : "npm run puggy & ng serve"`.

Your `package.json` should look like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start" : "npm run puggy & ng serve",
    "puggy": "pug src -P -w",
    . . . other tasks
}
```

Now, simply run `npm start`, or whatever name you gave to the task, in your terminal and you should see all of your `.pug` files getting compiled/watched/rendered and then everything served up.

I suggest you to add all of your `.html` files into your `.gitignore` adding `/src/**/*.html` into it and only pushing `.pug` files to your repo. Make sure you remove cached `.html` files using `git rm --cached *.html`.

Now you'll be able to write a form like

```
form(novalidate, '#f'='ngForm', '(ngSubmit)'='onSignin(f)')
```

And compile it into it's html

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSignin(f)"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the (fairly brittle) ng-cli-pug-loader method for years.  It served a purpose, and I'm thankful for it, but I developed a (slightly less brittle) way to add pug support.  It is not automagic via the Angular CLI - perhaps someone can help with that?  But for now it's not too many steps for what I think is a superior solution.

I documented that [Angular pug solution here](https://github.com/rmckeel/Angular-Pug-Support-Example) for posterity, check the top of the README for an explanation.

And if you want an even less brittle method (that does not create a new AngularCompilerPlugin), check out [angular.webpack.js](https://github.com/rmckeel/Angular-Pug-Support-Example/blob/master/angular.webpack.js) and the function `addSimplePugSupport`.

If you see a problem with this, please let me know via comments here or on my Git repo.

Answer (score -4):

If you want Stylus instead.

```
{
    test:/\.styl$/,
    use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'stylus-loader'],           
}
```

the config for SCSS has been changed

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
    exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
 }
```

Comment: I can't see how your this answer answers the question... CSS preprocessors have absolutely nothing with Jade/Pug.

Comment: Wrong, first add '.pug' to 'extensions'  and      {
          test: /\.(pug|jade)$/,
          use: ['pug-ng-html-loader']
        }, to module.rules  in webpack.common.js, then npm install pug pug-ng-html-loader,  then use pug file paths in templateUrl